# Jest ignore __mocks__ directory inside root

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have roughly the following structure

```
Root
├ __tests__
├ Directory0
│  ├ childA
│  │   └ __mocks__
│  │         └ module_a.js
│  └ childB        
│      └ __mocks__
│            └ module_a.js
├ Directory1
│    └ …
├ Directory2
│    └ …
└ DirectoryN
```

I'm trying to setup jest for the root directory, but completely ignoring `Directory0`
root tests would live in `__tests__`, some child directories have their own jest configuration and are tested separately, there are duplicated mocks [as those are templates that get copied, so no way to have a single shared mock] and jest is picking those mocks and emitting a warning.

I've already tried 
`testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/Directory0/']`
with no success

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this what you're looking for:
Add `__tests__` to your list of `roots` in `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  roots: [`<rootDir>/__tests__`],
};
```

References:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2726#issuecomment-390625860

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what @Harrison Kamau said with "roots" config.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#roots-arraystring

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest/setEnvVariables.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/packages/"
    ],
    "roots": ["<rootDir>/src/"]
  },
```

Worked for me, ignored mocks in my packages folder.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your package.json were you have the jest config

```
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.{js,jsx}",
  "!**/Directory0/**"
],
```

Change the `"**/*.{js,jsx}",` to match your case.

Read more in here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array

Comment: How would it this affect `__mocks__` resolution?  `collectCoverageFrom`
just affects the coverage reports, it doesn't prevent jest from reading from `Directory0`, it just omits it from the reports which isn't what I want